# calendar beside form: visual studio code

Tags: html, forms, responsive-design

I'm using visual studio code and trying to setup a page for a website where the calendar is beside the submission form. [This is what I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK11O.png)

These are my css and html codes, respectively:

```css
/*ALL*/

#event {
  width: 668px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-style: 2rem solid;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}


/*Calendar*/

h2,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/*form*/

input[type=text] {
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic;
  border: none;
}

input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic;
  border: none;
}

input[type=date] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic;
  border: none;
}

input[type=tel] {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-style: italic;
  border: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #016ABC;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #0066A2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  font-style: bold;
  box-shadow: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-style: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: rgb(63, 220, 168);
  color: black;
}

input[type=reset] {
  background: #016ABC;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #0066A2;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  font-style: bold;
  box-shadow: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-style: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type=reset]:hover {
  background: rgb(150, 09, 0);
  color: white;
}


/*responsiveness*/

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .parent {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eventt.css">
  <script src="javascript/contact.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="event">
    <section class="parent">
      <section class="child">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
                <h2>Month</h2>
                <h1>Calendar</h1>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Sun</th>
              <th>Mon</th>
              <th>Tue</th>
              <th>Wed</th>
              <th>Thu</th>
              <th>Fri</th>
              <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>21</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>24</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>26</td>
              <td>27</td>
              <td>28</td>
              <td>29</td>
              <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>31</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </section>
      <section class="child">
        <form>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">
                <h2>Fill the Form Below</h2>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for fname>First name:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" required id="fname" name="first name" placeholder="first name" Onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for lname>Last name:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" Onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for email>Your Email:</label></td>
              <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for date>Date:</label></td>
              <td><input type="date" id="date" value="date" name="date" placeholder="desired date of event" min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label></td>
              <td><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}" placeholder="Your number: 123-45-678" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Do you need a band or just a percussionist?</td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" id="band" name="radio" required>Band
                <input type="radio" id="Bobby" name="radio">Bobby
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="reset" name="button" value="reset"></td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="button" value="submit"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am facing ***three problems***; *they aren't being centered*, *they don't stack on top of each other if I make the screen smaller*, and
[it isn't being responsive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELKL0.png) [it appears as if the tables are somehow not connected, if that makes sense?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FI3i.png)

I would appreciate any help that I can get, thank you in advance, by the way, [I am aiming for something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEhEa.png) (but instead of the events, I want a submission form)

Comment: why not flex in all cases

Comment: you mean change all of "box-sizing: border-box" to "display: flex"? @rioV8

Comment: it gives me something very weird, especially when I change `*{box-sizing: border box}` to `*{display: flex}`

Comment: where in your CSS do you have `flex`?

Comment: using a `*` selector slows the CSS engine

Comment: I went back and re-wrote the entire html code; I contained both form and calendar in the same div container, then I placed the calendar inside of a table, divs, and lists. I also placed the form inside of a form, div, and list, instead of a table (tr, thread, etc.). It worked out as I wanted. Thank you @rioV8